# Fade out and fade in texture over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am changing a texture upon an event trigger. At the moment the change is quite abrupt. I would like to make the transition so that the current texture fades out and the next texture fades in (using the `_Glow` parameter. Both transitions should happen over a period of 3 seconds.

So far I was able to make the fade in but it is for 12sec. Should I use two coroutines?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class VFXController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AssetBundle assetBundle;
    private Texture texture;
    private Texture nextTexture;
    private Renderer renderer;
    public GameObject visual;

    private float currentGlowValue = 0.0f;
    private float targetGlowValue = 12.6f;

    private IEnumerator toggleTexture;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "session_vfx_textures"));
        if (assetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
            return;
        }

        renderer = visual.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        toggleTexture = ToggleTexture(12.6f);

        InitEvents();
    }

    private void InitEvents()
    {
        EventsManager.current.onChangeVFXTexture += ChangeTexture;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        EventsManager.current.onChangeVFXTexture -= ChangeTexture;
    }

    private void ChangeTexture(SessionNames name)
    {
        nextTexture = assetBundle.LoadAsset<Texture>(name.ToString());
        StartCoroutine(toggleTexture);
    }

    IEnumerator ToggleTexture(float duration)
    {
        for (float t = 0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            renderer.material.SetFloat("_Glow", currentGlowValue + t);

            yield return null;

            if (renderer.material.GetFloat("_Glow") >= 12.0f)
            {
                renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", nextTexture);
                StopCoroutine(toggleTexture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to create a Fade in/out effect using a coroutine. Here is the solution.

```
IEnumerator Fade()
        {
            float elapsedTime = 0;

            while (elapsedTime < transitionDuration)
            {
                currentGlowValue = Mathf.Lerp(13.0f, 0.0f, (elapsedTime / transitionDuration));
                visual.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_Glow", currentGlowValue);
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }

            visual.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_MainTex", nextTexture);

            elapsedTime = 0;

            while (elapsedTime < transitionDuration)
            {
                currentGlowValue = Mathf.Lerp(0.0f, 13.0f, (elapsedTime / transitionDuration));
                visual.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_Glow", currentGlowValue);
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Range in the shader for _GLOW property. It might be set Range(0,15) or something. If you want to bring it upto 3 seconds then change range to `_Glow ("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1`